# maibox restore can't locate source mailbox

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

I've been banging my head and searching for answers for this for about a day and a half now.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?  Both mailboxes are shared mailboxes, one is soft deleted the other is active.

```
PS> (get-mailbox -SoftDeletedMailbox recoverytest@mydomain.com).ExchangeGUID

Guid
----
222d4b9c-6439-4eec-b467-143353667ace


PS> (get-mailbox recoverydestination@mydomain.com).ExchangeGUID

Guid
----
af5cbbcb-2366-4cf1-80df-a518b5e47b1b


PS> New-MailboxRestoreRequest -SourceMailbox 222d4b9c-6439-4eec-b467-143353667ace -TargetMailbox af5cbbcb-2366-4cf1-80df-a518b5e47b1b -Verbose
Mailbox "222d4b9c-6439-4eec-b467-143353667ace" doesn't exist on database "NAMPR15DG135-db049".
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-MailboxRestoreRequest], MRSRemotePermanentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=BN7PR15MB2340,RequestId=aaf723b2-0951-47a9-8f8a-19a618f800ec,TimeStamp=11/19/201
   9 3:34:08 PM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-MRSRemotePermanentException] BE96E07B,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Migratio
  n.MailboxReplication.MailboxRestoreRequest.NewMailboxRestoreRequest
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I played myself.

If the mailbox has nothing in it when you delete it, it will show as being in the recycle bin BUT, you can't do anything with it other than view attributes.  I was able to do another test with a source mailbox that had 1 item in it and did not run into this issue.

Fun stuff.

Answer (score 0):

> > Mailbox "222d4b9c-6439-4eec-b467-143353667ace" doesn't exist on database "NAMPR15DG135-db049"

According to the error, you could run the following command to check whether the soft-deleted mailbox is on the database "**NAMPR15DG135-db049**":
 ***(Get-mailbox -SoftDeletedMailbox recoverytest@mydomain.com).Database***

I just tested restoring soft-deleted mailbox by running the command which you used earlier, but PowerShell reported an error:
[image]

I searched for some document about the error, then I added the **-AllowLegacyDNMismatch** parameter in the command. When I ran the new command in the PowerShell, the restore request was in Queued Status.
[image]

("**The parameter specifies that the operation should continue if the LegacyExchangeDN of the source physical mailbox and the target mailbox don't match. You don't need to specify a value with this switch.**"—From the official document ***[New-MailboxRestoreRequest](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/new-mailboxrestorerequest?view=exchange-ps)***).

After a while, EAC returned a notification(The restore is complete):

[image]

The new command made the restore request have a good running, so you could try to add the parameter in the command(***New-MailboxRestoreRequest -SourceMailbox 222d4b9c-6439-4eec-b467-143353667ace -TargetMailbox af5cbbcb-2366-4cf1-80df-a518b5e47b1b -AllowLegacyDNMismatch -Verbose***) and then check whether the error still exists.

Hope everything goes well with you!

Comment: Hi Ivan,

Thanks for the reply!

I tried this and I've still got the same error.

The search continues!

Answer (score 0):

> > Mailbox "222d4b9c-6439-4eec-b467-143353667ace" doesn't exist on database "NAMPR15DG135-db049".

According to this error, you could try to use the command ***(Get-mailbox -SoftDeletedMailbox recoverytest@mydomain.com).Database*** to check whehter the soft-deleted mailbox is on the database "**NAMPR15DG135-db049**", it may be the cause of the issue.